# How to set bounds and constraints on Tensorflow Variables (tf.Variable)

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I am using Tensorflow to minimize a function. The function takes about 10 parameters. Every single parameter has bounds, e.g. a minimum and a maximum value the parameter is allowed to take. For example, the parameter x1 needs to be between 1 and 10.

I also have a pair of parameters that need to have the following constraint x2 > x3. In other words, x2 must always be bigger than x3. (In addition to this, x2 and x3 also have bounds, similarly to the example of x1 above.)

I know that tf.Variable has a "constraint" argument, however I can't really find any examples or documentation on how to use this to achieve the bounds and constraints as mentioned above.

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to me (I can be mistaken) that **constrained optimization** (you can google for it in tensorflow) is not exactly the case for which tensroflow was designed. You may want to take a look at [this repo](https://github.com/google-research/tensorflow_constrained_optimization), it may satisfy your needs, but as far as I understand, it's still not solving arbitrary constrained optimization, just some classification problems with labels and features, compatible with precision/recall scores.

If you want to use constraints on the tensorflow variable (i.e. some function applied after gradient step - which you can do manually also - by taking variable values, doing manipulations, and reassigning then), it means that you will be cutting variables after each step done using gradient in *general space*. It's a question whether you will successfully reach the right optimization goal this way, or your variables will stuck at boundaries, because `general` gradient will point somewhere outside.

**My approach 1**

If your problem is simple enough. you can try to parametrize your `x2` and `x3` as `x2 = x3 + t`, and then try to do cutting in the graph:

```
x3 = tf.get_variable('x3',
                   dtype=tf.float32,
                   shape=(1,),
                   initializer=tf.random_uniform_initializer(minval=1., maxval=10.),
                   constraint=lambda z: tf.clip_by_value(z, 1, 10))
t = tf.get_variable('t',
                   dtype=tf.float32,
                   shape=(1,),
                   initializer=tf.random_uniform_initializer(minval=1., maxval=10.),
                   constraint=lambda z: tf.clip_by_value(z, 1, 10))
x2 = x3 + t
```

Then, on a separate call additionally do

`sess.run(tf.assign(x2, tf.clip_by_value(x2, 1.0, 10.0)))`

But my opinion is that it won't work well.

**My approach 2**

I would also try to invent some loss terms to keep variables within constraints, which is more likely to work. For example, constraint for x2 to be in the interval `[1,10]` will be:

`loss += alpha*tf.abs(tf.math.tan(((x-5.5)/4.5)*pi/2))`

Here the expression under `tan` is brought to `-pi/2,pi/2` and then `tan` function is used to make it grow very rapidly when it reaches boundaries. In this case I think you're more likely to find your optimum, but again the loss weight `alpha` might be too big and training will stuck somewhere nearby, if required value of `x2` lies near the boundary. In this case you can try to use smaller `alpha`.

Comment: "But my opinion is that it won't work well." Can you comment on why you think the `constraint` approach wont work well?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer by Slowpoke, reparameterization is another option. E.g. let's say you have a param `p` which should be bounded in [lower_bound,upper_bound], you could write:

```py
p_inner = tf.Variable(...)  # unbounded
p = tf.sigmoid(p_inner) * (upper_bound - lower_bound) + lower_bound
```

However, this will change the behavior of gradient descent.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Slowpoke, the Approach 1 seems to work well with some slight modifications in my case (in Python 3.10, Tensorflow 2.14.0):

1. Create a `tf.Variable` with the pre-defined constraint function:

```
z = tf.Variable(..., constraint=lambda x: tf.clip_by_value(x, 0.0, 1.0))
```

2. Compute the gradients and apply them to the variables; and then the constraint function will be applied to the tf variable `z` after being updated by the Optimizer (see the [official documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Variable)), by following the pre-defined constraint (i.e., between `0.0` and `1.0`):

```
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    tape = loss_func(...)
grads = tape.gradient(loss_func, z)
optimizer.apply_gradients(grads, z)
```